# Is it possible to ignore a cucumber hook if a specific tag is being used

Tags: cucumberjs

**Is it possible to ignore a hook if a specific tag is being used?**

If @someTag is used then I need the beforeAll to refer to an import with the alias, 's2'. 
Otherwise I need the beforeAll to refer to scope without the alias, 's'.

If I run a test with @someTag, then I would expect to only see 'In BeforeAll @someTag - hooks.js' printed in the console - but instead, they both run.

```
import s from "../location1/s";
import * as s2 from "../location2/s";

BeforeAll("not @someTag", async () => {
  console.log("In BeforeAll - hooks.js");
  s.driver = puppeteer;
})
BeforeAll("@someTag", async () => {
  console.log("In BeforeAll @someTag - hooks.js");
  s2.driver = puppeteer;
});
```

Comment: Instead of using word 'not' in Before function, use symbol '~' and try once

Comment: Which version of CucumberJS are you using? The newer versions use `not` but the older ones use `~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, CucumberJS does not support tag filters or the world object in the `beforeAll` and `afterAll` hooks because that data is simply not available at these points in the lifecycle of the test run. [The only supported parameter for these hooks is an optional callback](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/hooks.md#beforeall--afterall).

If you need to switch some sort of high-level object like a web driver at runtime, consider using a configuration file package such as [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) or an environment variable.